# Escaping Underscore with Xpath in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am baffled. Given this HTML:

```
<div class="v-product">
    <div class="v-product__inner">
        <a href="https://www.xxxxx.com/>
    </div>
<div class="v-product__details"> Description </div>
</div>
```

I want to get a node using XPath and Nokogiri.

I tried

```
parse_page.xpath("//v-product__details")
```

but it doesn't work as the node is empty.

How do I escape a double underscore in XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the underscore, its your XPath.

```
//v-product__details
```

is looking for a tag like `<v-product__details>`, not something with `v-product__details` in its `class` attribute.

I'd use CSS for this instead:

```
parse_page.css('.v-product__details')
```

But if you must use XPath:

```
parse_page.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "v-product__inner")]')
parse_page.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "v-product__inner")]')
parse_page.xpath('//div[@class="v-product__inner"]')
parse_page.xpath('//*[@class="v-product__inner"]')
...
```

And if `parse_page` came from `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(...)` then you'll want to add a leading `.` to your XPath expressions:

```
parse_page.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "v-product__inner")]')
...
```

But really, I'd go with CSS if possible.

Comment: Makes sense! I will try it and let you know. I used  parse_page ||= Nokogiri::HTML.parse(doc) many thanks

Comment: Even the Nokogiri documentation recommends CSS selectors over XPath. They're easier to read and for most things they'll work as well.